# shopt -s extdebug in .bashrc not working in script files

Tags: bash, shell-script, bashrc, shopt

I am writing a a bash script `echoo.sh` with the intention of echoing commands before they are executed. I source the script inside `.bashrc`. But it does not affect other bash scripts that I run. Below is the code I have so far:

echoo.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
shopt -s extdebug
get_hacked () {
    [ -n "$COMP_LINE" ] && return  # not needed for completion
    [ "$BASH_COMMAND" = "$PROMPT_COMMAND" ] && return # not needed for prompt
    local this_command=$BASH_COMMAND;
    echo $this_command;
}
trap 'get_hacked' DEBUG
```

When I open a shell and run any command - It works. But for stuff in a script file it doesn't work.

SOME FURTHER TRIES:

1. I tried sourcing the `.bashrc` file within the test script - it didn't work.
2. I sourced `echoo.sh` inside of the test script and it worked.

So, I am trying to understand

1. Why doesn't it work if I just source my script in `.bashrc` for stuff that runs in scripts?
2. Why doesn't further try #1 work when #2 does.

And, finally, what can I do such that I don't have to source `echoo.sh` in all script files for this to work. Can I source my script in one place and change some setting such that it works in all scenarios.

Comment: `]shopt`? With the bracket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested all your tries, and it worked on archlinux, bash version 4.4.12.
But I had to open a new interactive shell, so the new `~/.bashrc` could be sourced.

For non-interactive shells you could also try to setup an `~/.bashenvrc` and set `export BASH_ENV=$(realpath ~/.bashenvrc)` in `~/.bashrc`.

Now the script `~/bashenvrc` will be sourced every time you start an non-interactive shell.

I tested this also with *daemonize 1.7.7-1*

cheers

Comment: Hey.. Thanks for trying it out.. I know it works for interactive shells. I am trying to get to work on non interactive shells as well

Comment: Hey.. no problem. I will need this too. So I edited my answer, please try my suggestion.

Comment: Can you have a look at [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/422653/im-trying-to-prevent-the-execution-of-a-command-in-bash-doesnt-work-always) ??